# How to count an include inside a another include sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables, and i need to count how much Cupons my table orders have, my table Cupons belongs to my table orders, and my table orders belong to my table Afiliado, i need to fetch all 'Afiliates', and get all Orders and all Cupons of the order and count the Cupons, i tried this way but doesn't work

```
var Afiliadosorders = afiliados.map(async (item) => {
            return await Afiliados.findByPk(item.id, {
                include: {
                    model: Orders,
                    as: 'Ordens',
                    attributes: {
                        include: [
                            'order_id'
                            [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Cupons.id")), "CuponsCount"]
                        ],
                        separate:true,
                        limit: 1
                    },
                    include: {
                        model: Cupom,
                        as: 'Cupons',
                    },
                },
            })
        })
```

@EDIT
It's solved with the @Anatoly comment, with subquery, the finally solution if somebody else have the same issue

`````
var Afiliadosorders = afiliados.map(async (item) => {
            return await Afiliados.findByPk(item.id, {
                include: {
                    model: Orders,
                    as: 'Ordens',
                    required: true,
                    attributes: {
                        include: [
                            [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cupom where cupom.order_id = "Ordens"."id")'), "Total_Cupons"]
                        ],
                    }
                },
            })
        })
    ````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get how many Cupons in a certain Afiliados then you can try to go by a reverse way starting from Cupons:

```js
return await Cupom.count({
  include: [{
    model: Orders,
    required: true,
    attributes: [],
    as: 'Ordens',
    where: {
       // indicate the real PK field name here
       afiliadosId: item.id
    }
  }]
})
```

If you wish to get order details then you need to use subquery and remove `include` option for Cupom:

```js
return await Afiliados.findByPk(item.id, {
                include: {
                    model: Orders,
                    as: 'Ordens',
                    attributes: {
                        include: [
                            [Sequelize.literal("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cupom where Cupom.order_id = Ordens.id)"), "CuponsCount"]
                        ],
                    },
                },
            })
```

Comment: But i need to show the data of the order and the data of afiliados, this way worked but only count how many coupons the affiliate has

Comment: Look at the updated answer

Comment: I tried an return this error 'original: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ordens", i'm searching for the solution for this error

Comment: Look at generated SQL query and fix the alias for Orders table in the subquery

Comment: Is not pushing the Ordens.id, is passing the string Ordens.id to the subquery i have tried something like ${Orders.id}

Comment: Thank you, i find the solution, is just a litle sintax error i change the "Ordens.id" to "Ordens"."id" and worked, thank you!